How to add foreign key that references table without C# model
I wanted to create migration with ef migrations add, all my migrations are written with fluent api but I came across a problem.
How to properly store enum values in the database?
Best option would be to create new table with Id and Name (enum). It would look something like this:
public enum EngineType
{
    Steam = 1,
    Gasoline = 2,
}

----------------------------------------------

modelBuilder.Entity("EngineType", builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("DIC_ENGINE_TYPES");
            
    builder.Property<int>("Id")
        .HasColumnName("ID")
        .IsRequired();
    builder.HasKey("ID");

    builder.Property<string>("Name")
        .HasColumnName("NAME")
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasIndex("Name")
        .IsUnique();
            
    foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues<EngineType>())
    {
        builder.HasData(new { Id = (int)enumValue, Name = enumValue.ToString() });
    }
});

This works fine however I don't know how to add foreign key relationship in my other entities.
For example I want to create an Engines table with column ENGINE_TYPE_ID that references DIC_ENGINE_TYPES:
public class Engine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EngineType EngineType { get; set; }
}

----------------------------------------------

modelBuilder.Entity<Engine>(builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("ENGINES");
    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasColumnName("ID")
        .UseIdentityColumn()
        .IsRequired();

    builder.Property(x => x.EngineType)
        .HasColumnName("ENGINE_TYPE_ID")
        .IsRequired();

    // TODO: add constraint to EngineType, HasOne doesn't work
});

I know that I could write migration manually but is there a way to do add this shadow constraint with fluent api?

you have taken a wrong process. If you were to create a table, there is no need for an enum. But if you want to look at it as data, remove its reference from your tables and use the   foreign key of the EngineType table and when creating the database, seed the enum data in EngineType table.
